# Python parser output from command

Tags: python, parsing, output, extract

I retrive this output with a curl command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><restQueuedBuild planKey="project-build001" buildNumber="123" buildResultKey="project-build001-123"><triggerReason>Manual build</triggerReason><link href="https://mybamboo.server.com/rest/api/latest/result/project-build001-123" rel="self"/></restQueuedBuild>
```

**How to get** in buildNumber volue **123** in python?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><restQueuedBuild planKey="project-build001" buildNumber="123" buildResultKey="project-build001-123"><triggerReason>Manual build</triggerReason><link href="https://mybamboo.server.com/rest/api/latest/result/project-build001-123" rel="self"/></restQueuedBuild>')


print(root.get('buildNumber'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use *BeautifulSoup* package. You can install via pip like that

> pip install BeautifulSoup

Do this for you get the desired result

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><restQueuedBuild planKey="project-build001" buildNumber="123" buildResultKey="project-build001-123"><triggerReason>Manual build</triggerReason><link href="https://mybamboo.server.com/rest/api/latest/result/project-build001-123" rel="self"/></restQueuedBuild>', 'lxml')

subResult = soup.find('restqueuedbuild')
result = subResult['buildnumber']
print result
```

Font: https://linuxhint.com/parse_xml_python_beautifulsoup/